# Mobile Food Schedule Android App(using Kotlin)

Tags: android, api, kotlin

Im facing a problem Kotlin. short-Long history, im trying to get the data from json using Retrofit2. So, i have the json link(https://data.sfgov.org/resource/jjew-r69b.json) but, how do i know what is the: GET, baseUrl, and Query. Because I need to pass the right context.

here how my code look like:

that's the interface file:

interface FoodTruckService {

```
@GET("jjew-r69b.json")
fun listFoodTruck(
    @Query("api_Key") apiKey: String): Call<Location2>
```

}

this is the FoodTruckDbClient Object:

object FoodTruckDbClient {

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(" https://data.sfgov.org/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()


val service = retrofit.create(FoodTruckService::class.java)
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would recommend taking the time to take a look at [ask]. In particular, your title should reflect the problem you're facing, by reading your question it is clear that food schedule's have no relevance.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed resource use resource/jjew-r69b.json

```
@GET("resourse/jjew-r69b.json")
fun listFoodTruck(
  @Query("api_Key") apiKey: String): Call<Location2>
```

BTW Do you need api_key? since this API is giving result without one.